# Complex MySQL query using group by

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have two tables

```
Table1:
product_id, design1, design2
1              A        C
2              B        A

Table2:
product_id, value
1             10
2             10
```

Now i want to to sum all the value for particular design for all products.

```
SELECT designA, SUM(value) FROM ( 
 SELECT b.design1 AS designA, SUM(value) AS value FROM table2 AS a LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id GROUP BY b.design1) AS T GROUP BY designA

It gives me this:
designA SUM(value)
  A           10
  B           10
```

Now the problem is that if user has specified design2 in table1 then what ever is the value of design1 will automatically be added in design2. If design2 is not present design1 column then it will be a new row of result:

Desited result is this:

```
designA SUM(value)
  A            20
  B            10
  C            10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select y.designA, sum(value) from 

(select  a.design1 as designA, value from
Table1 as a
inner join Table2 as b
on
a.product_id = b.product_id

union all

select a.design2 as designA, value from
Table1 as a
inner join Table2 as b
on
a.product_id = b.product_id) as y 
group by y.designA
```

seems to work for your test data, not tried on other configurations but you should be able to tweak it, if you understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

UNION in the matches based on design2:

```
SELECT designA, SUM(value) FROM ( 
 SELECT b.design1 AS designA, SUM(value) AS value FROM table2 AS a LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id GROUP BY b.design1
UNION
 SELECT b.design2 AS designA, SUM(value) AS value FROM table2 AS a LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id GROUP BY b.design2
) AS T GROUP BY designA
```

Comment: It still gives me two rows A=10 and B=10

Comment: Oops: forgot to update the GROUP BY statement in the 2nd half of the UNION

Comment: ok now it gives me three rows, with values A=10, B=10, C=10. But value of should be A=20 because in table1 row2 what ever is the value of design1(which is B) should be added in A because design2 is A of row2